# Why am I not able to get output? the same data location perfctly works in another code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract data from an excel file and past it into another new sheet, however it seems like the file directory is wrong.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

data_location = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\barış\Desktop\y2.xlsx")
desired_headings = ["Valuable Information"]
df_total = pd.DataFrame(columns=desired_headings)

for file in os.listdir(data_location):
    df_file = pd.read_excel(data_location + file)
    selected_columns = df_file.loc[:, desired_headings]
    df_total = pd.concat([selected_columns,df_total],ignore_index=True)

df_total.to_excel("ValuableInformation.xlsx")
```

OUTPUT:

```
File "C:\Users\barış\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Trial 8.py", line 8, in <module>
for file in os.listdir(data_location):
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not DataFrame
```

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct:

for file in os.listdir(data_locat`enter code here`ion):

Comment: I think you should have `data_location = r'C:\Users\...'`. Don't use read_excel function on this line since it's already done in later code.

Comment: Apart from the invalid syntax `pd.read_excel()` returns a data frame. As stated in the error, that's not valid. You need to turn it into a list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
data_location = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\barış\Desktop\y2.xlsx")
```

so data_location is a dataframe.
Then you have

```
for file in os.listdir(data_locat`enter code here`ion):
```

os.listdir expects a directory not a dataframe so maybe try something like this instead

```
for file in os.listdir("C:\Users\barış\Desktop")
```